# Protected Routes in React-Ionic app using Firebase Auth Context

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I'm trying to set up a context for Firebase authentication in a React-Ionic app with some protected routes which shouldn't be accessible without being authenticated. So far it kinda works, but not completely. I can log in with no problems and navigate the pages with protected routes, but as soon as I refresh the page, it takes me back to the login page as if I weren't authenticated.

I'm pretty sure I'm messing things up somewhere but haven't been able to detect where (it's actually possible that the whole thing is wrongly implemented, as I'm quite new to this and still learning).

This is how my files look so far (without imports and stuff, just the core part):

**App.tsx**:

```
const App: React.FC = () => {

  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(authContext) **//**
  }, [])  

  return (
    <IonApp>
      <IonReactRouter>
        <IonRouterOutlet>
          <Route exact path="/" component={PageLogin} />
          <ProtectedRoute path="/secure/home" component={PageHome} isAuthenticated={authContext.authenticated!}/>
          <ProtectedRoute path="/secure/lot/:lotId" component={PageLotOverview} isAuthenticated={authContext.authenticated!}/>
          <ProtectedRoute path="/secure/shipment/:shipmentId" component={PageShipmentOverview} isAuthenticated={authContext.authenticated!}/>
        </IonRouterOutlet>
      </IonReactRouter>
    </IonApp>
  )
}
```

**AuthProvider.tsx:**

```
export const AuthContext = React.createContext<Partial<ContextProps>>({});

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: any) => {

  const [user, setUser] = useState(null as firebase.User | null);
  const [loadingAuthState, setLoadingAuthState] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user: any) => {
      setUser(user);
      setLoadingAuthState(false);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        authenticated: user !== null,
        setUser,
        loadingAuthState
      }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

**ProtectedRoute.tsx:**

```
interface ProtectedRouteProps extends RouteProps {
  component: React.ComponentType<any>;
  path: string;
  isAuthenticated: boolean
}


export const ProtectedRoute: React.FC<ProtectedRouteProps> = ({ component: Component, path, isAuthenticated }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("from protected ROUTE", isAuthenticated)
  }, [])

return (
    <Route path={path} render={() => isAuthenticated ? <Component /> : <Redirect to="/" />} />
  );
};
```

**index.tsx:**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <AuthProvider>
    <App />
  </AuthProvider>
  , document.getElementById('root'));
```

Please let me know if I can provide more useful information. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Number 1: **Every One are still Learning**.

Number 2: There is a very simple solution for this which I personally use (works fine). You can use something called '*session storage*' facility.

As soon as you get the user data from Firebase do this :

```
// When login is successful

window.sessionStorage.setItem('isLogged', 'true'); 

// This will create a variable with value *true* that 
can be accessed from any page within your website
```

Session Storage is like a local database that can store any number of values you want to save and don't get erased on refresh. However it is just temporary and will get erased when the user closes the browser window.

Now at every protected routes you can do this.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(window.sessionStorage.getItem('isLogged') == 'false')
  {
    window.location.href = '/login' // send the user to login page
  }
}, [])
```

**Pro Tip**:

Use can use this mechanism to implement '*Remember Me*' option for whatever you are developing. In that case you may have to use `LocalStorage` which is similar to `sessionStorage` but it won't erase the data even when the user closes the browser window.

And again when the user visits your page, it will automatically redirect the user to the main page without logging in (if you create a `useEffect` to check that).

Another thing : Both `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` are different for different user. The values stored in my browser's `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` will not be visible to you or anyone for that matter except me.

That's it

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer, I really appreciate it. If I understood correctly, with your approach it wouldn't be necessary to have the "ProtectedRoute" component anymore, right? I have to just use normal Route components and place an useEffect checking for the sessionStorage at every page that requires authentication and that's it. Well, in that case I don't even see why having the AuthContext would be useful anymore. In these kind of situations it gets a little confusing for me. Your solution seems so simple, why would one even bother to set up an AuthContext in first place?